# PostgreSQL Error: Column "Income" specified more than once

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to build a basic database to help sift through many CSV bank transactions.

I've imported all my transactions in several tables from various accounts that have columns for 'Deductions' that I have ticked "False or "True"

I'm trying to do a 'Create View' To source from the many tables into one table for 'Deductions'.

Basicaly;
**bank transactions from multiple tables with Income column reads "TRUE"**

> The Error is - Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  column "Income" specified more
>   than once

I have been trying out various lines of codes for about a day, but can't seem to get it to work.

```
CREATE VIEW "Deductions" AS
SELECT
    "EverydaySTG"."Income",
    "EverydaySTG"."Deduction",
    "EverydaySTG"."Date",
    "EverydaySTG"."Amount",
    "EverydaySTG"."Payee",
    "CC WTPC"."Income",
    "CC WTPC"."Deduction",
    "CC WTPC"."Date",
    "CC WTPC"."Amount"
FROM
    "EverydaySTG",
    "CC WTPC"
WHERE (
    "EverydaySTG"."Deduction" = 'TRUE' ::text)
    Or(
        "CC WTPC"."Deduction" = 'TRUE' ::text
);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are more than one Income column in your statement:  `"EverydaySTG"."Income"` and `"CC WTPC"."Income"`. Replace..:

```
CREATE VIEW "Deductions"
AS SELECT
    "EverydaySTG"."Income",
    "EverydaySTG"."Deduction",
    "EverydaySTG"."Date",
    "EverydaySTG"."Amount", 
    "EverydaySTG"."Payee",
    "CC WTPC"."Income",
    "CC WTPC"."Deduction",
    "CC WTPC"."Date",
    "CC WTPC"."Amount"
FROM
    "EverydaySTG", "CC WTPC"
WHERE (
    "EverydaySTG"."Deduction" = 'TRUE' ::text)
    Or ( "CC WTPC"."Deduction" = 'TRUE' ::text );
```

... by:

```
CREATE VIEW "Deductions"
AS SELECT
    "EverydaySTG"."Income" AS income_a,
    "EverydaySTG"."Deduction" AS deduction_a,
    "EverydaySTG"."Date" AS date_a,
    "EverydaySTG"."Amount" AS amount_a,
    "EverydaySTG"."Payee",
    "CC WTPC"."Income" AS income_b,
    "CC WTPC"."Deduction" AS deduction_b,
    "CC WTPC"."Date" AS date_b,
    "CC WTPC"."Amount" AS amount_b
FROM "EverydaySTG", "CC WTPC"
WHERE (
    "EverydaySTG"."Deduction" = 'TRUE' ::text)
    Or( "CC WTPC"."Deduction" = 'TRUE' ::text );
```

---

OP comments "The result is the transactions have populated horizontally. Instead of the clean single rows of Income, deduction, date, amount ect. Is there a way to keep the original rows in tact, so the transactions stack vertically?".

I understand they want a UNION query instead:

```
CREATE TABLE "EverydaySTG" (
    "Income" INTEGER
    "Deduction" CHARACTER VARYING
    "Date" DATE
    "Amount" INTEGER
    "Payee" CHARACTER VARYING
);

CREATE TABLE "CC WTPC" (
    "Income" INTEGER
    "Deduction" CHARACTER VARYING
    "Date" DATE
    "Amount" INTEGER
);
```

```
CREATE VIEW "Deductions_horizontal"
AS SELECT
    "EverydaySTG"."Income" AS income_a,
    "EverydaySTG"."Deduction" AS deduction_a,
    "EverydaySTG"."Date" AS date_a,
    "EverydaySTG"."Amount" AS amount_a,
    "EverydaySTG"."Payee",
    "CC WTPC"."Income" AS income_b,
    "CC WTPC"."Deduction" AS deduction_b,
    "CC WTPC"."Date" AS date_b,
    "CC WTPC"."Amount" AS amount_b
FROM "EverydaySTG", "CC WTPC"
WHERE (
    "EverydaySTG"."Deduction" = 'TRUE' ::text)
    Or( "CC WTPC"."Deduction" = 'TRUE' ::text );
```

```
CREATE VIEW "Deductions_vertical" AS
    SELECT
        "EverydaySTG"."Income",
        "EverydaySTG"."Deduction",
        "EverydaySTG"."Date",
        "EverydaySTG"."Amount", 
        "EverydaySTG"."Payee",
    FROM "EverydaySTG"
    WHERE "EverydaySTG"."Deduction" = 'TRUE'
    UNION
    SELECT 
        "CC WTPC"."Income",
        "CC WTPC"."Deduction",
        "CC WTPC"."Date",
        "CC WTPC"."Amount",
        NULL AS "Payee"
    FROM "CC WTPC"
    WHERE "CC WTPC"."Deduction" = 'TRUE';
```

Comment: Hey Uprego, Thank-you for helping with this code. The result is the transactions have populated horizontally. Instead of the clean single rows of Income, deduction, date, amount ect.

Is there a way to keep the original rows in tact, so the transactions stack vertically?

Answer (score 0):

do thye fact that your selevct obtain the same column name form tow table you have as result the same column name but in sql can't use the same column name must change eg:

```
CREATE VIEW "Deductions" AS
SELECT
  "EverydaySTG"."Income",
  "EverydaySTG"."Deduction",
  "EverydaySTG"."Date",
  "EverydaySTG"."Amount",
  "EverydaySTG"."Payee",
  "CC WTPC"."Income" AS Income_cc_wtpc,
  "CC WTPC"."Deduction" AS Deduction_cc_wtpc,
  "CC WTPC"."Date" AS Date_cc_wtpc,
  "CC WTPC"."Amount" AS Amount_cc_wtpc
FROM
  "EverydaySTG",
  "CC WTPC"
WHERE (
  "EverydaySTG"."Deduction" = 'TRUE' ::text)
  Or(
    "CC WTPC"."Deduction" = 'TRUE' ::text
);
```